# C++ adapting a library for multithreading

Tags: c++, oop

I'm working with libconfig++ and threads for making a small server application. The point is, [libconfig++ is not thread safe](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/libconfig_manual.html#Multithreading-Issues), so my idea is to create another class which acts as a wrapper with a Mutex, something like this:

```
class app_config {
public:
    app_config();
    /* Here be my problems. */
    void set(); 
    void get();
    virtual ~app_config();

private:
    Config cfg;
    boost::mutex *cfg_mutex;
};
```

Now, this is all good until I realize that [libconfig supports plenty of types](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/libconfig_manual.html#Configuration-Files) for its variables. And thats when our protagonist (me) finds himself in search of any C++ guru with a kind heart willing to show him any way to get this working.

Essentially, the `get` and `set` functions would need a `std::string` or a `char*` `path` variable containing the path to the configuration file's variable (I wouldn't mind using either) and the return type (or the second argument in the `set`'s case) should vary...

As always, any help will be appreciated.

Julian

Comment: Be careful with lifetime management of the mutex.  Either make `app_config` noncopyable and use a `mutex` member (instead of a `mutex*`) or use a `unique_ptr<mutex>` member and define your own copy operations to create a new instance.

Comment: Oh, this is because of the mutex being noncopyable, right?. Thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could as well use this approach. I think it more difficult to missuse and therefore superior. The Libconfig instance is a private member inside of the wrapper and can't be accessed without a lock.

```
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/locks.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

class Libconfig {
public:
    int Get(const char*) { return 0; }
};

class LibConfLock;

class LibconfMultithreadingWrapper {
    friend class LibConfLock;
public:
    LibconfMultithreadingWrapper()
        :m_Libconfig(new Libconfig())
        ,m_Mutex(new boost::mutex())
    {}

private:
    boost::shared_ptr<Libconfig> m_Libconfig;
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::mutex> m_Mutex;
};

class LibConfLock  {
public:
    LibConfLock(const LibconfMultithreadingWrapper& wrapper)
        :m_Libconfig(wrapper.m_Libconfig)
        ,m_Mutex(wrapper.m_Mutex)
        ,m_Lock(new LockType(*m_Mutex))
    {}
    Libconfig& GetLibconf() const { return *m_Libconfig; }
private:
    typedef boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> LockType;
    boost::shared_ptr<Libconfig> m_Libconfig;
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::mutex> m_Mutex;
    boost::shared_ptr<LockType> m_Lock;
};

int main() {
    LibconfMultithreadingWrapper wrapper;
    int i = LibConfLock(wrapper).GetLibconf().Get("hallo");

    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a decorator class that forwards all function calls to a private libconfig instance. This means you need to add all the functions you want to use to your decorator.
Another possibility is to forward the call to libconfig to a class that does the actual locking.

```
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/locks.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

class MultithreadingWrapper {
public:
    template <class V, class T>
    V ExecuteThreadSaveWithReturn(T func) {
        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> l(m_Mutex);
        return func();
    }

    template <class T>
    void ExecuteThreadSave(T func) {
        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> l(m_Mutex);
        func();
    }

private:
    boost::mutex m_Mutex;
};

void f() {}
void f(int) { }
int f(int, int) { return 0; }

int main() {
    MultithreadingWrapper wrapper;
    wrapper.ExecuteThreadSave(boost::bind(f));
    wrapper.ExecuteThreadSave(boost::bind(f, 1));
    int i = wrapper.ExecuteThreadSaveWithReturn<int>(boost::bind(f, 1, 1));
    return i;
}
```

Comment: This is a really good approach, I'll keep the question open though, kind of interested in seeing what other alternatives there are.

EDIT: what would actually happen with exceptions?

Comment: @JulianBayardoSpadafora Exceptions would propagate through the wrapper and should be handled where you call wrapper.ExecuteThreadSave. The lock would be reset even when a exception is thrown since the lock is deleted at the end of the ExecuteThreadSave function.